# SQL - Return first non-empty value for previous days

Tags: sql-server, function

I'm currently working with an exchange rates table in SQL that has these fields:

`| Country | ExchangeRateDt | ExchangeRateValue |`
 `| DK      | 202000601      |       0.2         |`
 `| DK      | 202000603      |       0.21        |`
 `| HR      | 202000601      |       0.10        |`
 `| HR      | 202000602      |       0.12        |`

For each currency I don't have a value for any day of the year because of bank holidays or simply weekends.

I need to join it with an order table where some orders are placed on weekends and on a specific day I could not have an exchange rate to calculate taxes.
I need to take the first non missing value from  the previous days (so in the examples should I have an order for day 2020-06-02 in Denmark I should exchange it using the rate 0.2)

I thought about using a calendar table but I can't manage to get the job done.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance,

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically create a calendar table that stores all the days you are interested in, say `dates`, with each date on a separate row.

You would also probably have a table that lists the countries: I assumed `countries`.

Then, one option is a lateral join:

```
select c.country, d.date, t.ExchangeRateValue 
from dates d
cross join countries c 
outer apply (
    select top (1) t.*
    from mytable t
    where t.country = c.country and t.ExchangeRateDt <= d.date
    order by t.ExchangeRateDt desc limit 1
) t
```

If you don't have these two tables, or can't create them, then one option is a recursive query to generate the dates and a subquery to list the countries. For example, this would generate the data for the month of June:

```
with dates as (
    select '20200601' date
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, date) from dates where date < '20200701'
)
    select c.country, d.date, t.ExchangeRateValue 
from dates d
cross join (select distinct country from mytable) c 
outer apply (
    select top (1) t.*
    from mytable t
    where t.country = c.country and t.ExchangeRateDt <= d.date
    order by t.ExchangeRateDt desc limit 1
) t
```

Comment: I got both tables but it kept returning the same rate for every day.Thanks tho!

Comment: @Polymar: the `order by` has the wrong direction... Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much sir

Answer (score 3):

To get the most recent value less than or equal to the current day:

```
SELECT
  <whatever columns you need from order>
 ,exchange.ExchangeRateValue
FROM
  <order table> order
LEFT JOIN
  <exchange rate table> exchange
    ON exchange.Country = order.Country
        AND exchange.ExchangeRateDt =
              (
                SELECT
                  MAX(ExchangeRateDt)
                FROM
                  <exchange rate table>
                WHERE
                  Country = order.Country
                    AND ExchangeRateDt <= order.OrderDt
              )
```

Ensure the clustered index on the exchange rate table is (Country, ExchangeRateDt).

I have this as a left join so you will still return order results if the currency information is somehow missing.  You would have to refer to business rules on how to proceed if no exchange rate was available.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the mapping between the transation date and the exchange rate date with this query:

```
select TAB.primary_key, TAB.TransationDate, max(EXR.ExchangeRateDt)
from yourtable TAB
inner join exchangerate EXR
on TAB.Country = EXR.Country and TAB.TransationDate >= EXR.ExchangeRateDt
group by TAB.primary_key, TAB.TransationDate
```